# Connecting SAP BO to Hive CSVSerde does not exist

Tags: hive, odbc, business-objects

I have connected SAP BO to Hive using a ODBC driver.
I am able to see the database and table in Hive, but when I fetch data from Hive it gives error as

> org.apache.hadoop.hìve.serde2.SerDeExceptio SerDe com,bizohive.serde.csv.CSVSerde does not exist

Can anyone suggest where I should put csvserde jar in SAP BO?

Answer (score 0):

The serde should be in the HIVE `lib` directory. Try copying it there, and reconnecting to Hive from BO.

Comment: Can you try `hive --auxpath your_serde.jar` ?

Comment: error is on SAP BO side after connecting while fetching m getting error in BO UI

Comment: Do you mean that you're able to fetch the data in Hive shell?

Comment: Also, I think it might be worth taking a look at the ODBC file in BO. I guess the path is `\some_path\dataAccess\connectionServer`. `some_path` refers to the BO install directory and the appropriate OS path. You will find a file for `ODBC` in there and you could try adding the `HIVE` lib path to the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: yea i can fetch in hive shell but not in BO